# How to block ad blocker in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

My React native project contains ads. I don't want ad blockers to get in the way of this. I tried the https://www.npmjs.com/package/adblock-detect-react package but it didn't work. Can't I use a package written for React in react native? Is there any way to block ad blockers in React native?